# KDE - Plasma becomes glitchy with Intellij Idea launched

Tags: linux, debian, intellij-idea, debian-jessie, kde-plasma-5

I am using Debian Jessie with KDE. When I am working with opened IntelliJ IDEA, almost all windows in Plasma become so:

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Version of IntelliJ Ultimate is 15.0.3.

Comment: Did you have the same problem with IntelliJ **14** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `apt-get upgrade` problem disappeared.